# Creation of data frame with variable that counts number of observations by group

Tags: r, dataframe, summarize, mutate

I am trying to create a new data frame where the mean, sd, variation and number of observations by group are created into new variables. The code below is provided as an example, using the built in data set of 'CO2' in the car pacakge.

```
library(plyr)
library(fixest)
library(car)
library(pander)

##Using the built-in CO2 data frame, run regression
View(CO2)

CO2_summarized<-ddply(CO2, ~Plant,plyr:::summarise, mean = mean(conc), sd = sd(conc), var = var(conc), obs = n())
summary(CO2_summarized)
```

Creating the data frame with the mean, sd, and variation variables by plant group works. However, the creation of a variable that counts the number of observation by plant group does not work. This is the `obs = n()` part of the code. The error given is `` Error in `n()`: ! Must be used inside dplyr verbs. `` Looking for solutions to this error or an alternative way.

Comment: The error indicates that `dplyr` is loaded, but your code does not include it. It is better to use the newer `dplyr` than the older `plyr` and you certainly should not use both libraries at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use `plyr`, but it might be better to transition to `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

CO2 |>
  group_by(Plant) |>
  summarise(mean = mean(conc), 
            sd = sd(conc), 
            var = var(conc), 
            obs = n())
#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#>    Plant  mean    sd    var   obs
#>    <ord> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
#>  1 Qn1     435  318. 100950     7
#>  2 Qn2     435  318. 100950     7
#>  3 Qn3     435  318. 100950     7
#>  4 Qc1     435  318. 100950     7
#>  5 Qc3     435  318. 100950     7
#>  6 Qc2     435  318. 100950     7
#>  7 Mn3     435  318. 100950     7
#>  8 Mn2     435  318. 100950     7
#>  9 Mn1     435  318. 100950     7
#> 10 Mc2     435  318. 100950     7
#> 11 Mc3     435  318. 100950     7
#> 12 Mc1     435  318. 100950     7
```